# 2D grid of JComponents (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jcomponent, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a 2D grid of JTextFields to represent a level map. I've come to the following for initializing the 2D Array of TextFields:

```
fields = new TextField[level.rows][level.columns];
TextField field;
    for (int r = 0; r < level.rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < level.columns; c++) {
            field = new TextField(level.bricks[r][c].type);
            fields[r][c] = field;
        }
```

Now I have to add them to the JFrame, but they need to be lined up so that every `row` gets under the other column. I did find GridLayout, however i'm not very experienced with AWT/Swing, and still don't know how achieve the desired layout. I was expecting there to be some kind of method like `gLayout.add(JComponent,row,column)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work as you explained, here's a fully working example that puts `JLabels` in the 5x5 Grid:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridPrb {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        Label l = new Label("x=" + x + ",y=" + y);
        cp.add(l);
      }
    }
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The end result would look something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod Agree, for any non-example application, the above should be run on the EDT.

Comment: personally, I think that all full code examples should stick as strictly as possible to best practices - newbies need to be reminded of them again and again (and tend to remember the not-so-good-pratices better ;-) But then, I don't follow my own advice always, +1 for the sscce :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be careful about adding order, container is filled column after column in GridLayout.

```
frame.setLayout( new GridLayout( level.rows, level.columns );

for (int c = 0; c < level.columns; r++) 
    for (int r = 0; r < level.rows; c++) 
         frame.add(fields[r][c]);
```

Comment: so does GridLayout just put the component on the end, till the row is full, and then start on the next one?

Comment: No it fills the column, then starts the next column.

Comment: Actually GridLayout may behave differently in adding order, but as far as you add elements with respect to the #rows and #columns it works as i explained.

Comment: @deporter : In GridLayout first the Row gets filled, and then it moves to the next Row. Not the other way around as you told in your comment. Moreover it depends on the  container's ComponentOrientation, but either way first Row gets filled not Column.